# Command Prompt "Net View System Error 6118"

Tags: windows, command-line

When I try to use "net view" in command prompt, I get an error code 6118. What does this mean, and how can I fix it? Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

6118 means The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available, mostly it is due to the firewall protection blocks the SMB.

You can check as following steps

1. first check each pc is in the same workgroup.
2. disable the firewall and virus protect in each PC.
3. Ping PC2 from PC1 to ensure the network is ok
4. net view \PC2 from PC1 to check if it is ok.

Comment: Firewall and my antivirus are off/disabled. What else can I try?

Comment: do you have a DNS server in your intranet? try to restart it.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "DNS server in my internet" means, but I restarted my modem regardless... no change.

Comment: modem? Does you computer belongs to a workgroup, or it just a single machine connected to internet?

Comment: No, there are multiple computers connected to my home network. "net view" should show me the computers that are connected to it, right?

Comment: you can try this:
1. first check each pc is in the same workgroup.
2. disable the firewall and virus protect in each PC.
3. Ping PC2 from PC1 to ensure the network is ok
4. net view \\PC2 from PC to check if it is ok.