# Exception - "The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available (NetServerEnum)"

Tags: c#, exception

I am using a third party api but I do not have access to it's support.

I am using the following code which is throwing an exception.

```
string ipaddress = "192.168.1.7";
ClientConnection conn = ApiFactory.CreateConnection("https://" + ipaddress + ":4411/api", "13.0.0.0");
```

**{"The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available  (NetServerEnum)"}**

ipaddress = "192.168.1.7" is the local ip address of my machine.

What could be the possible reason for this particular exception.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676714/command-prompt-net-view-system-error-6118

Comment: @stuartd No, my application runs locally and involves no other machines as answered in above

Comment: What does parameter `"13.0.0.0"` mean?

Comment: Its the api version